# Syncing folders in Vagrant- error message

Tags: vagrant, synchronization

I had syncing folders working fine from my mac to my vagrant vm but now i am getting an error whenever i try to 'vagrant up'.
This is the line in my vagrantfile that i am using:

```
     config.vm.synced_folder “../data", "/vagrant_data"
```

and this is the error that i am seeing:

```
 There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. 

 The syntax error
 message is reproduced below for convenience:

 /Users/mbair2/dl_webcast/Vagrantfile:43: unknown regexp options - vagrat
 /Users/mbair2/dl_webcast/Vagrantfile:43: syntax error, unexpected      
 tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
config.vm.synced_folder “../data", "/vagrant_data"
                                                   ^
```

i have the host folder ../data in place. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After  reinstalling i found out that i had an extra 'space' that was causing the problem.